# What exactly are the parabolic subgroups of a relatively hyperbolic group, in the context of this paper by Dahmani-Groves?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I'm currently reading this [1] paper of Dahmani-Groves, relating to detecting splittings of relatively hyperbolic groups.

The paper makes many references to the *parabolic subgroups* of a group $G$ which is relatively hyperbolic to a collection of subgroups $\mathcal P$. I don't see a definition of this term in the paper itself, nor in Bowditch's article [2] on the subject.

I suspect this might simply refer to the elements of $\mathcal P$, but I've seen these referred to as *peripheral* subgroups elsewhere. It also seems like the term "parabolic subgroup" is overloaded in group theory, so Google is unhelpful.

Any clarification/help/reference would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**References**

[1] Dahmani, François, and Daniel Groves. "Detecting free splittings in relatively hyperbolic groups." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society (2008): 6303-6318.

[2] Bowditch, Brian H. "Relatively hyperbolic groups." International Journal of Algebra and Computation 22.03 (2012): 1250016.

Comment: It's just different terminology, same meaning as "peripheral."

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for, thank you!